# PyWebIO and Browser-Updates

Tags: python, web-applications, cefpython, pywebview

i`m using pywebio to develop input-screens for our measurement operations - it works just great. The input-screens run only locally.

Concerns have been issued that PyWebIO is using the Standardbrowser. Since the browsers on our computers might be updated by IT-department unannounced or a new browser might be mandatory and use of the old one for webbrowsing forbidden - it would potentially mean that the PyWebIO input-screens do not work properly anymore.

From what i was able to find out on the internet, there are two solutions to this:

1. Dont use browser-based GUI-libraries, but instead tkinter or wxpython which use the widgets and graphics "native" to the operating system and are therefore not dependent on the browser.
2. Use an embedded browser. Find some library which opens the GUI in an embedded browser and deploy this browser/library with the whole application, so it doesnt get updated by IT.
   From what i found, Pywebview and PythonCEF might be possible solutions, but from the docs im not quite sure that they *really* dont use any outside source or even the browser installed on the local machine. Also, i dont find any useful examples except for maybe this (wasnt able to get it running so far):

https://gist.github.com/mkeneqa/3abac79204e903c71d1483674aed0a3f

Any help or comments on my findings would be greatly appreciated.

I tried to google my problem and searched pywebio-docs and stackoverflow but couldnt find any useful answers.